# Extension of Dedekind domains with the same quotient field

Tags: reference-request, commutative-algebra, dedekind-domain

Let $K$ be a field. Let $A \subseteq B$ be an extension of Dedekind domains that are both finitely generated $K$-algebras. Assume that $A$ and $B$ have the same quotient field. Can we find an element $s \in A$ such that $B$ equals the localization $A_s$?

I would be very glad if this was a statement in some book, but a (not too complicated) proof would also be fine.

Comment: Same quotient field or field of fractions?

Comment: for me both are the same: the localization of A with respect to the multiplicative set $A\smallsetminus \{0\}$. (not to confuse with "quotient ring" where I divide out an ideal)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is in general false. Take such an $A$, with $F$, the fraction field. Assume that there exists a prime ideal $P\subset A$ which is non-torsion in the Picard group. (These are plenty and happens more often than otherwise). Take $B$ to be the set of all $a\in F$ such that $aP^n\subset A$  for some $n$. Then $A\subset B$ and easy to see that $B\neq A_s$ for any $s\in A$.

Comment: Hi Mohan, thanks for your answer. I think I understand why $B \neq A_s$ for any $s \in A$. What I don't see is that $B$ is a finitely generated $K$-algebra. Can you also give me a proof for that?

Comment: Easiest way is, for a suitable $g\not\in P$, $P$ in $A_g$ is principal generated by say $b$ and thus $B_g=A_g[b^{-1}]$. Now, you can find an $f\in P$ such that the ideal generated by $f,g$ is $A$ and $A_f=B_f$. Put them together to get finite generation.